# how to adjust panel.borders in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have drawn a simple barplot:

```
mtcars$cnames = rownames(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars[1:5,], aes(cnames, disp)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.5),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=5))
```

and as you can see by running this example borders are going thrugh the axis.text.
How to make borders lower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what are you looking for :

```
  mtcars$cnames = rownames(mtcars)
ggplot(mtcars[1:5,], aes(cnames, disp)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 0.5),
          plot.background = element_rect(colour = "black", fill=NA, size=5))
```

Comment: i change the `panel.border` by `plot.background`